# Pivoting columns for a table with SQL (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, pivot, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, left-join

I have 3 tables that I need to join, with the endresult being a pivot of certain columns.

The situation is as follows:

Table 1

| ID | COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C | COLUMN_G | NN_COLUMN_H | NN_COLUMN_I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | Aa | 123aa | null | null |
| 1 | 20 | 2 | Aa | 56211 | blah | null |
| 1 | 30 | 3 | Aa | 123aa | vvvv | null |
| 2 | 40 | 4 | Bb | 678cf | null | null |
| 2 | 50 | 5 | Bb | 56211 | blah | mmmm |

Table 2

| ID | COLUMN_C | COLUMN_J | NN_COLUMN_K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aa_G | Aa | AaA | null |
| Aa_G | Bb | AaA | null |
| Aa_G | Cc | AaA | 1234 |
| Aa_G | Dd | AaA | 5678 |

Table3

| ID | COLUMN_D | COLUMN_E | COLUMN_F | COLUMN_L | NN_COLUMN_M | NN_COLUMN_N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VALUE1 | 10 | 01-03-2024 | True | 12 | 0000a |
| 1 | VALUE1 | 11 | 02-03-2024 | True | 34 | 0000b |
| 1 | VALUE2 | 10 | 01-03-2024 | True | 56 | 0000b |
| 2 | VALUE1 | 15 | 01-03-2024 | True | 78 | 0000b |
| 2 | VALUE2 | 12 | 01-03-2024 | True | 89 | 0000s |
| 2 | VALUE2 | 12 | 02-03-2024 | True | 45 | 00001 |

Table 4, the endresult

| ID | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | COLUMN_F | COLUMN_C | COLUMN_G | COLUMN_J | COLUMN_L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 | 01-03-2024 | Aa | Aa_G | AaA | True |
| 1 | 11 | null | 02-03-2024 | Aa | Aa_G | AaA | True |
| 2 | 15 | 12 | 01-03-2024 | Bb | Aa_G | AaA | True |
| 2 | null | 12 | 02-03-2024 | Bb | Aa_G | AaA | True |

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
TABLE3
LEFT JOIN TABLE1
ON TABLE3.ID = TABLE1.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.COLUMN_C = TABLE2.COLUMN_C
WHERE TABLE3.COLUMN_D in ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')
```

However, I'm stuck as to where or how to implement the PIVOT line.
The columns that should be pivoted are column_D and column_E in table3.

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all information as editable text so that someone can copy your data/tables if they want to try out a solution

Comment: Endresult (``1``, 15, 12, 01-03-2024, Bb, Aa_G)--> (``2``, 15, 12, 01-03-2024, Bb, Aa_G) ?

Comment: @ValNik Yes, you're right. I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example

```
select id
  ,max(case when column_d='VALUE1' then column_e end)value1
  ,max(case when column_d='VALUE2' then column_e end)value2
  ,column_f
from table3
group by id,column_f
order by id,column_f;
```

Case when more than 1 (Id,VALUEx) per date

```
select id
  ,max(case when column_d='VALUE1' then column_e end)value1
  ,max(case when column_d='VALUE2' then column_e end)value2
  ,column_f,rn
from (
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by id,column_f,column_d order by column_f)rn
  from table3
)t
group by id,column_f,rn
order by id,column_f,rn;
```

Join as

```
select *
from(
  select id
    ,max(case when column_d='VALUE1' then column_e end)value1
    ,max(case when column_d='VALUE2' then column_e end)value2
    ,column_f
  from table3
  WHERE TABLE3.COLUMN_D in ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2')
  group by id,column_f
)t3
LEFT JOIN TABLE1
ON T3.ID = TABLE1.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.COLUMN_C = TABLE2.COLUMN_C
order by t3.id,t3.column_f;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5hPF3miB)

Comment: this did the trick... Thank you! An additional question, say that I have other columns from table 3 and/or table 1 and 2 that I need to add. Where in the query do I place them? Because I tried it by replacing the select * with the columns that I wanted to add, and I received an error message. I think primarily when it involved the other table 3 columns. @ValNik

Comment: Add an example of additional data to the current question or ask another question. For additional columns in Table 3, you need to understand how they will be grouped.

Comment: I added to the original question. As you can see I added columns with the NN_prefix to my tables. Al the other columns that don't have the prefix are columns that I need within my endresult. In reality of course there are more columns that I do and don't need, but this is just a sample. In the third part of your query I changed the "select * " to selecting only the needed columns, But this didn't work. Thanks again for your help. @ValNik

Comment: You can add ``max(COLUMN_L) column_l`` or ``min(COLUMN_L) column_l`` or other aggregate function with COLUMN_L.